# Google drive api v3 "code": 401, "message": "Login Required"

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to save a file to google drive using Google Drive V3 api and OAuth 2.0 from a browser in JavaScript.

my code is as follows :

```
<pre><code>
var startApp = function() {
      gapi.load('auth2', function(){
          // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
          auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
              discoveryDocs:'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest',
              client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
              api_key:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
              scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
          });
      oauthToken = googleUser.Zi.access_token;
      });
      gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', null); 
  };

 function sendfile(formData){
        var myPostRequest = new ajaxRequest();
        myPostRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if (myPostRequest.readyState == 4){
            if (myPostRequest.status == 200){
              var  data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              console.log('file uploaded: ', data)
            }
            console.log(''image upload not successful: ', this.responseText);
          }
        };
        myPostRequest.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=contentHints%2Fthumbnail%2Cid%2CimageMediaMetadata%2CisAppAuthorized%2CmimeType%2CwebContentLink%2CwebViewLink&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx', true);
        myPostRequest.send(formData);
    }

logInButton.onClick = startApp();
```

i keep on getting this 401 message in response to the post request:

```
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "required",
     "message": "Login Required",
     "locationType": "header",
     "location": "Authorization"
    }
  ],
   "code": 401,
   "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

what am i missing? do I need to supply the access token with the post request, or am I simply not properly logged in with the right authorization and scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing your code to the working [Javascript Quickstart for Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js), it looks like you're missing bits of code like:

```
// Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
```

which listens for state changes. Anyway, check the link for the full code implementation. It's what I use when playing with Drive API in JS.